# moving page up after creating new row

Tags: html, css

[image]

### Description

1. In the above image i have been creating new row after the plus button is clicked and i have been used jquery auto suggestion

[image]

### Description

1. The above image showing when i came to middle of the page

[image]

### Description

1. In the above image after i click plus button the save button below new and jquery suggestion result are not showing completely
   [image]

### What i needed

1. I need result like these when i enter new row the page should go up so that my suggestion result and other elements view completely

Comment: What we need: [mcve]

Comment: Based on what language you are writing your app, you should consider using a grid control, data grid or data repeater which handles auto scrollbar management.

Answer (score 0):

When a new row is added, do this command (JS):

```js
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
```

This will scroll to the bottom of the page.

If you have something below the list, for example a div of 10 height so you don't want to scroll to bottom:

```js
divHeight = 10
window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - divHeight)
```